# Firebase Firestore recycler view adapter duplicates the list for every document

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning to code and trying to follow the Kotlin messenger series on YT 'lets build that app'.

I am stuck at implementing a recycler view using Groupie and can't copy the code exactly as the series uses the older firebase database and I'm using firestore.

I am nearly there, but my list of 'farms' for my 'switch farm view' is duplicating each item 6 times, which is the number of documents in the collection (i.e. I get 6 copies of each farm name rather than just 1).

I think this must be an easy fix but I can't figure it out.

The problem I think is in here:

```
    private fun fetchFarms() {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
    db.collection("farms").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (document in result) {
            result.forEach {
            Log.d("SwitchFarmActivity","Loaded document: ${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            val farm = it.toObject(Farm::class.java)
            adapter.add(FarmItem(farm))
                }
            }
        recyclerview_switchfarm.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

The Log print out is actually returning two of each item, followed by a whole series of 
'ViewPostIme pointer 0'
'ViewPostIme pointer 1'
'ViewPostIme pointer 0'
'ViewPostIme pointer 1'.. etc

The 'Farm' class that gets generated is very basic:

```
data class Farm(val farmId: String, val farmName: String, val ownerId: String) {
constructor():this("","","")
```

}

This is the FarmItem class:

```
class FarmItem(val farm: Farm): Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.itemView.farmName_textView_switchFarm.text = farm.farmName
}
override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.farm_row_switch_farm
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I have a solution, thanks to Nguyễn for pointing me in the right direction.

```
    private fun fetchFarms() {
    Log.d("SwitchFarmActivity","fetchFarms function called")
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
    recyclerview_switchfarm.adapter = adapter
    db.collection("farms").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        val farmList = result.toObjects(Farm::class.java)
        farmList.forEach {
            Log.d("SwitchFarmActivity","Loaded document: $it")
            adapter.add(FarmItem(it))
        }

    }
}
```

If anyone has refactoring suggestions please share. I still don't quite understand why (for document in result) was getting run 36 times instead of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
private fun fetchFarms() {
val farmList = mutableListOf<Farm>()
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
recyclerview_switchfarm.adapter = adapter
db.collection("farms").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
    for (document in result) {
        result.forEach {
        Log.d("SwitchFarmActivity","Loaded document: ${document.id} => ${document.data}")
        val farm = it.toObject(Farm::class.java)
        farmList.add(farm)
            }
        }

}
adapter.addItems(farmList)
}
```

in GroupAdapter create method **addItems**

```
    fun addItems(list: List<Farm>) {
    itemList.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```

Comment: Hi I get an error at <adapter.add(FarmItem(farm))> saying type mismatch found 'farm' requires 'farmItem'. Also can you please be more specific about where to put the addItems method? is that in the FarmItem class? Added this class to the question body.

Comment: Thank you again, that error is fixed, but I still don't understand where to put the addItems function and also now there is no reference to the FarmItem class?